# Conditional Expectation of Stochastic Integral w.r.t a Martingale given path of the Martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I was wondering how to evaluate the following expression:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[\int_t^T\Delta_s dX_s \; |\{X_u\}_{t \leq u \leq T}]
\end{equation}

where the stochastic process $X$ is a martingale, and $\Delta$ is adapted.

I know that without the path of $X$, this would just be $0$, but now that its path is given, I am unsure how I can manipulate this expression. $T$ can be any time increment so $T = t + dt$ is also a possible choice, but I couldn't get anywhere conclusive using that. I am also wondering if there are certain conditions under which this expression would evaluate to $0$ (other than $\Delta = 0$), since for the problem I am working on that would be 'ideal'.

Thanks!

Comment: $t$ has no special role here, so assume $t =0$. Since $\Delta$ is adapted to the filtration of $X$ (call it $\mathcal{F}^X$), the whole integral $\int_0^{\cdot} \Delta_s \, d X_s$ is $\mathcal{F}^X$ adapted. So, $\int_0^T \Delta_s \, d X_s$ is $\mathcal{F}^X_T$ measurable and you have $$ E \left[ \int_0^T \Delta_s \,d X_s \mid \mathcal{F}^X_T\right] =  \int_0^T \Delta_s \,d X_s $$ almost surely.

Comment: So in the case where the upper limit was a stopping time, not measurable with respect to the natural filtration generated by $X$, there's no simplification?

Comment: Well, I assumed that $T$ was a fixed time. In case $T$ is a stopping time, recall that you should also have *some* filtration (say $\mathcal{G}$) in hand such that $\{T\leq t \} \in \mathcal{G}_t$ for all $t \geq 0$. My feeling is that any simplification of the conditional expectation given above will depend on the precise nature of the relationship between $\mathcal{F}^X$ and $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Okay. Thanks so much for your help!